# question about bcp utility in sql server

Tags: sql-server, bcp

If I have data rows in database and want to import data from data file with bcp utility in native mode, is there any solution (specified switch) that override data with same identity value in ID column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - `-E` to keep identity values in the file. Just type `bcp` at the command line to see a full list of options.

Comment: thanks david, my question is that if I have rows with duplicate identity value, what's the bcp manner? (I use -E switch)

Comment: No, you have to choose one way or the other - maintain the identities, or have new ones.